# node-opencv / mavericks : dyld: Symbol not found

Tags: node.js, opencv, osx-mavericks, build-error

I'm running a clean install of OSX 10.9 and running into issues running any **node.js** app with **[node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv)** dependencies. I've already installed **opencv**, **python**, **node.js**, and **npm** via **Homebrew**.

In this case, I'm trying to run: `node face_detection.js` from the [examples](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/tree/master/examples) folder, and I'm getting this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi
  Referenced from: /Users/Jim/GitHub/node-opencv/build/Release/opencv.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi
  Referenced from: /Users/Jim/GitHub/node-opencv/build/Release/opencv.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the cause was, I had the same problem and solved it by upgrading to the latest homebrew distribution of opencv.